# ASP.NET MVC Render to email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to send a bunch of emails, and the obvious way to format them is to render a partial view and send that. The problem is that I'd like to do this in the background, so it isn't immediately obvious how to get access to the methods I need.

Since the job is kicked off by a controller, one thing I was thinking of was something like this:

```
public ActionResult SendEmails(){
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSendEmails(
      // pass in a formatting closure that has access to the 
      // controller's context
      delegate(EmailData) {
           return RenderPartialToString("view", EmailData);
      }
  ));
}
```

Will this work? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hyper strongly recommend you [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) (note the *Send Email Asynchronously* section). You may also checkout [Scott Hanslemann's blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek2MvcMailerSendsMailsWithASPNETMVCRazorViewsAndScaffolding.aspx) about it.

Answer (score 3):

Another option to consider is [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/).  You can find a tutorial [here](http://aboutcode.net/2010/11/17/going-postal-generating-email-with-aspnet-mvc-view-engines.html) to get started, or watch [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Andrew-Davey-Going-Postal-Generating-email-with-View-Engines) from MvcConf.  You can send emails asynchronously using the `Email.SendAsync()` method.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a project called [ActionMailer.Net](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/ActionMailer) that allows you to generate emails from your MVC views.  Give it a spin and let me know if you like it.  I also wrote up some [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/wiki/Home) and a nice [screencast](http://geeksharp.com/2011/02/11/intro-to-actionmailer-net-screencast/) for the project.  Cheers! :)